# Multi-line Equation Inside Multiple Brackets Spanning Multiple Lines

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write a multi-line equation inside multiple brackets that span multiple lines. Here is a simplified example of what I concretely mean:
[image]
I am having difficulties in typesetting my equation exactly the same way. Will gratefully appreciate any help. Here is what I attempted so far (it's a different equation but I want to typeset it the same way; I also tried `align` and other environments but failed to make it work):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{0} = \mathbb{E}_{0}\left\{ \sum_{t=0}^ {\infty}\beta^{t} \left[ \log(C_{t}^{i}) - \frac{(N_{t}^{i})^{1 + \psi}}{1 + \psi} + \xi^{i} \log(h_{t}^{i})  + \lambda_{t} \left[ P_{t}C_{t}^{s} + Q_{t}^{d}P_{t}D_{t} + Q_{t}P_{t}B_{t}^{g} = P_{t} w_{t} N_{t}^{s} + Z_{t}^{d} P_{t-1} D_{t-1} + P_{t-1} B_{t-1}^{g} + \Gamma_{t} \right] \right] \right\}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

The above gives me this:
[image]

Comment: Instead of the `[....]` you could use the `pmatrix` env it of course supports multiple lines (`equation` does not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I adding my humble proposal with MWE and the screenshot. Surely there are many types to write an MWE with your request. 
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}_{0} ={E}_{0}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^ {\infty}\beta^{t} \Bigl[ \log(C_{t}^{i}) - \frac{(N_{t}^{i})^{1 + \psi}}{1 + \psi} + \xi^{i} \log(h_{t}^{i}) & \\
\lambda_{t} \Bigl[ P_{t}C_{t}^{s} + Q_{t}^{d}P_{t}D_{t} + Q_{t}P_{t}B_{t}^{g} = P_{t} w_{t} N_{t}^{s} + Z_{t}^{d} P_{t-1} D_{t-1} + P_{t-1} B_{t-1}^{g} + \Gamma_{t} \Bigr]\Bigr]
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}.
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted and thank you for that. Why do you use `\displaystyle` before `\sum....`? I never used it; I just went with `\sum...` whenever I needed it and am curious what the reasons are for using it. Your answer also helped me get the exact 'calligraphic' `L_{0}` that I had in the question. I suppose one needs to use `mathalfa` package for that. Is that right? What are those options `scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05`?

Comment: I am very happy to help you. The reason is that if you remove `\displaystyle` you have an ugly over-sub indices for the sum. In other words you will have a `\sum`inline mode. You can try to remove `\displaystyle` and you see the effect for the `\sum`. I remember a few calligraphic characters because I also use the package `mathalfa` and your observation are correct: they are the style of the calligraphic characters and the size.

Answer (score 1):

With use of `multlined` environment defined in the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{0} 
    = \mathbb{E}_{0}
    \left\{\begin{multlined}\sum_{t=0}^ {\infty}\beta^{t}
    \biggl[ \log(C_{t}^{i}) - \frac{(N_{t}^{i})^{1 + \psi}}{1 + \psi} + \xi^{i} \log(h_{t}^{i})  +    \\[-1ex]
    \lambda_{t}\Bigl[ P_{t}C_{t}^{s} + Q_{t}^{d}P_{t}D_{t} + Q_{t}P_{t}B_{t}^{g}
    = P_{t} w_{t} N_{t}^{s} + Z_{t}^{d} P_{t-1} D_{t-1} + P_{t-1} B_{t-1}^{g} + \Gamma_{t} \Bigr] \biggr]
            \end{multlined}
    \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]